# Display Custom Message when ValidateInput attribute false

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, dotnet-httpclient

I have a scenario where I need to display some user friendly message when the request URL contains html tags. I need this using ValidateInput attribute. For example, I have a method as below:

```
[ValidateInput(true)]
Public string testMethod(string test, string test1)
{
some implementation
}
```

In my scenario, if the request URL contains any html tags, I simply need to return some friendly message. I should not allow html in the request URL.

Please help me out with this. I am using MVC, C# for this.

Comment: not sure what you pretend.. but you need to specify a route in API!!

Comment: Yes, but in my case there is a scenario where the request URL might have html tags i.e, example <a></a> kind of. So if the URL contains it, I need to handle it from ValidateInput[] decorator. Like sending a friendly message to user

Comment: I am also looking answer to same kind of issue, please help if you have resolved it already